# A monoid $M$ is $\omega$-presentable in the category $M$-$\mathbf{Set}$

Tags: category-theory, order-theory, limits-colimits, monoid, morphism

I feel that this is true but I'm unable to prove it formally: a monoid $M$ is $\omega$-presentable in the category $M$-$\mathbf{Set}$. This is the category of $(X,\rho)$ where $\rho:M\times X\to X$ satisfies $(a\cdot b)\cdot x=a\cdot (b\cdot x)$ and $1\cdot x=x$. The explicit definition of finite presentability is given in the snippet below:

> **Definition.** An object $K$ of a category $\mathcal{K}$ is called *finitely presentable* provided that its hom-functor
>
> $$\operatorname{hom}(K, {-}) : \mathcal{K} \to \mathbf{Set}$$
>
> preserves directed colimits.
>
> Explicitly: $K$ is finitely presentable iff for each directed diagram
>
> $$D : (I, \le) \to \mathcal{K},$$
>
> each colimit cocone $D_i \overset{c_i}{\rightarrow} C ~ (= \operatorname{colim} D), i \in I$, and each morphism $f : K \to C$ there exists $i$ such that
>
> (1) $f$ factorizes through $c_i$, i.e., $f = c_i \cdot g ~ (i \in I)$ for some $g : K \to D_i$,
>
> and
>
> (2) the factorization is essentially unique in the sense that if $f = c_i \cdot g = c_i \cdot g'$, then $D(i \rightarrow j) \cdot g = D(i \rightarrow j) \cdot g'$ for some $j \ge i$.

[image]

Comment: Hyphen, not minus sign.

Comment: OK, first step would be to understand how the hom-functor $\operatorname{hom}_{M{-}\mathbf{Set}}(M, {-})$ acts.

Comment: @DanielSchepler A far too complex thing for me :-(

Comment: In fact, $\operatorname{hom}_{M{-}\mathbf{Set}}(M, {-})$ is isomorphic to the underlying set functor $M{-}\mathbf{Set} \to \mathbf{Set}$.  The basic idea is that an $M$-equivariant morphism from $M$ to an $M$-set $S$ is uniquely determined by where it sends the identity of $M$, and conversely, for any element $s$ of the underlying set of $S$, there is a morphism $M \to S$ defined by $m \mapsto m \cdot s$.  (You can also think of this as saying that $M$ is "the free $M$-set on one generator".)

Comment: @DanielSchepler Right. How the $\omega$-presentability of $M$ now follows ? At best not by some abstract argument but rather by a concrete one. BTW, how the free $M$-set on 2 generators look like ?

Comment: The finite presentability of $M$ follows from the fact that the underlying set functor respects directed colimits, i.e. the colimit of a diagram of $M$-sets is an action of $M$ on the directed colimit of the underlying sets of the $M$-sets.

Comment: And for your other question, the free $M$-set on 2 generators looks like $M \sqcup M$ (a disjoint union of two copies of $M$) where the action of $M$ is: $m \cdot left(m') = left(m m'), m \cdot right(m') = right(m m')$ (where $left$ and $right$ are the two maps $M \to M \sqcup M$).

Comment: @DanielSchepler Too fast for me: how can I see the fact that the underlying set functor respects directed colimits ? How can I prove it **directly** from the snippet part *Explicitly* ? I need this in order to properly grasp the concepts rather than using some abstract machinery.

Answer (score 2):

Let me first review a couple basic properties of directed limits of $M$-sets:

**Lemma 1:** Suppose $x \in \varinjlim D(i)$.  Then there exists some $i \in I$ and $x_i \in D(i)$ such that $x = c_i(x_i)$.

**Proof:** Consider $S := \bigcup_{i\in I} \operatorname{im}(c_i)$.  It is straightforward to show that this is a sub-$M$-set of $\varinjlim D(i)$; and by construction, each $c_i$ factors (uniquely) through $S$.  It follows that the factors of $c_i$ induce a morphism of $M$-sets $\varinjlim D(i) \to S$ such that composing with the inclusion map of $S$ gives the identity map on $\varinjlim D(i)$.  This implies that $S$ is all of $\varinjlim D(i)$.  $\square$

**Lemma 2:** Suppose $x_i \in D(i)$, $y_j \in D(j)$ satisfy $c_i(x_i) = c_j(y_j)$.  Then there exists $k \ge i, j$ such that $D(i\to k)(x_i) = D(j\to k)(y_j)$ in $D(k)$.

**Proof:** This one is a bit trickier.  One way to see this is to construct an $M$-set of so-called *germs of functions*.  Here, an element is given by some $i \in I$ and a function $f \in \prod_{j\ge i} D(j)$ -- i.e. $f$ is a function with domain $\{ j \in I \mid j \ge i \}$ such that for each $j\ge i$, we have $f(j) \in D(j)$.  However, we need to give a condition that two germs $f \in \prod_{j\ge i} D(j)$ and $f' \in \prod_{j\ge i'} D(j)$ are considered equal if there exists $i'' \ge i, i'$ such that $f(j) = f'(j)$ whenever $j \ge i''$.  (The proof that this gives an equivalence relation on "pre-germs" should be straightforward.)  We can define an action of $M$ on the set of pre-germs of functions, where $m \cdot f$ has the same domain as $f$ and $(m \cdot f)(j) := m \cdot (f(j))$.  (Check that this respects the equivalence relation, and therefore induces an $M$-set structure on the set $G$ of germs of functions.)

Now for each $i$, we can define a morphism of $M$-sets $D(i) \to G$ where $x \in D(i)$ maps to the pre-germ with domain $\{ j \in I \mid j \ge i \}$ and function $j \mapsto D(i\to j)(x)$, then to the corresponding germ.  It should be a straightforward exercise to show that this forms a compatible collection of morphisms $D(i) \to G$, and therefore induces a morphism $\varinjlim D(i) \to G$.

Now, suppose we have $x_i \in D(i), y_{i'} \in D(j)$ such that whenever $j \ge i, i'$, we have $D(i\to j)(x_i) \ne D(i'\to j)(y_{i'})$.  This would imply that the germs $j \mapsto D(i\to j)(x_i)$ and $j \mapsto D(i'\to j)(y_{i'})$ generated by $x_i$ and $y_{i'}$ respectively are unequal in $G$.  Therefore, we must have $c_i(x_i) \ne c_{i'}(y_{i'})$ in $\varinjlim D(i)$. $\square$

---

Note that an alternative proof for both lemmas would be to exploit the usual construction of a directed colimit of $M$-sets: start with $\bigsqcup_{i\in I} (\{ i \} \times D(i))$.  Then quotient by the equivalence relation where $(i, x_i) \sim (j, y_j)$ if there is some $k \ge i, j$ with $D(i\to k)(x_i) = D(j\to k)(y_j)$ in $D(k)$.  Show that this forms an $M$-set with action of $M$ induced by the action $m \cdot (i, x_i) := (i, m \cdot x_i)$.  Show that the canonical morphisms $D(i)$ to the quotient form a compatible collection, and show that this system satisfies the required universal property of the directed colimit.  Now, note that under this construction, both lemmas are pretty much immediate.

---

Now, finally, to show directly that the explicit conditions are satisfied:

(1) Suppose we have a morphism of $M$-sets $f : M \to \varinjlim D(i)$.  Then by lemma 1, there exists some $i \in I$ and $x_i \in D(i)$ such that $f(e) = c_i(x_i)$.  Now define $g : M \to D(i)$ by $g(m) := m \cdot x_i$.  It is straightforward to check that $g$ is a morphism of $M$-sets.  Also, for any $m \in M$, $$f(m) = f(m\cdot e) = m \cdot f(e) = m \cdot c_i(x_i) = c_i(m\cdot x_i) = c_i(g(m)),$$ so $f = c_i \circ g$ as required.

(2) Suppose we have two morphisms of $M$-sets $g, g' : M \to D(i)$ such that $c_i \circ g = c_i \circ g'$.  Then by lemma 2, there exists some $j\ge i$ such that $D(i\to j)(g(e)) = D(i\to j)(g'(e))$.  This implies that for any $m\in M$, $$D(i\to j)(g(m)) = D(i\to j)(g(m\cdot e)) = m \cdot D(i\to j)(g(e)) = m \cdot D(i\to j)(g'(e)) \\ = D(i\to j)(g'(m\cdot e)) = D(i\to j)(g'(m)),$$ so $D(i\to j) \circ g = D(i\to j) \circ g'$ as required.

Comment: I'm now studying your pretty long answer. I may have more questions later, but for now: why each $c_i$ factors uniquely through $S$ ?

Comment: Because $\operatorname{im}(c_i) \subseteq S$.

Comment: Right. And why the composition with inclusion gives the identity on $\varinjlim D(i)$ and how it follows that $S$ is all of $\varinjlim D(i)$ ?

Comment: Well, if $h$ is the induced morphism $\varinjlim D(i) \to S$, then by construction $h \circ c_i$ is the factor of $c_i$ through $S$, so $\operatorname{inc}_S \circ h \circ c_i = c_i = \operatorname{id} \circ c_i$.  Therefore, by the uniqueness part of the universal property of $\varinjlim D(i)$, $\operatorname{inc}_S \circ h = \operatorname{id}$.

Comment: And then, for every $x \in \varinjlim D(i)$, we have $x = \operatorname{inc}_S(h(x)) \in S$.